# VLC: Webcam stream not showing

Tags: vlc-media-player

I am trying to stream my webcam feed through my Network but the receiving client cannot view and get the error: "VLC is unable to open the MRL." I tried to follow the instructions from [here](http://www.guidingtech.com/9554/vlc-stream-media-live-camera-feed-how-to/).

I tried doing it locally with the Windows 7 Enterprise firewall turned off using HTTP as destination. I created the stream using the destination of HTTP on port 8082 and checked on "Display locally". I set the http port to 8082. I can see my camera feed here fine.

I opened another instance of VLC to view the stream and pointed to `http://127.0.0.1:8082`, but get the error message: "VLC is unable to open the MRL '`http://127.0.0.1:8082`'. Check the log for details."

Looking at Messages (verbose 2) debug window displays the following:

```
main debug: processing request item: http://127.0.0.1:8082, node: Playlist, skip: 0
main debug: resyncing on http://127.0.0.1:8082
main debug: http://127.0.0.1:8082 is at 1
main debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
main debug: resyncing on http://127.0.0.1:8082
main debug: http://127.0.0.1:8082 is at 1
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'http://127.0.0.1:8082'
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path 'C:\Users\01roc1\AppData\Local\Temp'
main debug: `http://127.0.0.1:8082' gives access `http' demux `' path `127.0.0.1:8082'
main debug: creating demux: access='http' demux='' location='127.0.0.1:8082' file='\\127.0.0.1:8082'
main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "http": 12 candidates
main debug: no access_demux modules matched
main debug: creating access 'http' location='127.0.0.1:8082', path='\\127.0.0.1:8082'
main debug: looking for access module matching "http": 20 candidates
access_http debug: querying proxy for http://127.0.0.1:8082
access_http debug: no proxy
access_http debug: http: server='127.0.0.1' port=8082 file=''
main debug: net: connecting to 127.0.0.1 port 8082
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
main warning: connection timed out
access_http error: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:8082
main debug: net: connecting to 127.0.0.1 port 8082
main warning: connection timed out
access_mms error: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:8082
main debug: no access modules matched
main error: open of `http://127.0.0.1:8082' failed
main debug: dead input
main debug: changing item without a request (current 1/2)
main debug: nothing to play
qt4 debug: IM: Deleting the input
main debug: processing request item: http://127.0.0.1:8082, node: Playlist, skip: 0
main debug: resyncing on http://127.0.0.1:8082
main debug: http://127.0.0.1:8082 is at 1
main debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
main debug: resyncing on http://127.0.0.1:8082
main debug: http://127.0.0.1:8082 is at 1
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'http://127.0.0.1:8082'
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path 'C:\Users\01roc1\AppData\Local\Temp'
main debug: `http://127.0.0.1:8082' gives access `http' demux `' path `127.0.0.1:8082'
main debug: creating demux: access='http' demux='' location='127.0.0.1:8082' file='\\127.0.0.1:8082'
main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "http": 12 candidates
main debug: no access_demux modules matched
main debug: creating access 'http' location='127.0.0.1:8082', path='\\127.0.0.1:8082'
main debug: looking for access module matching "http": 20 candidates
access_http debug: querying proxy for http://127.0.0.1:8082
access_http debug: no proxy
access_http debug: http: server='127.0.0.1' port=8082 file=''
main debug: net: connecting to 127.0.0.1 port 8082
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
main warning: connection timed out
access_http error: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:8082
main debug: net: connecting to 127.0.0.1 port 8082
main warning: connection timed out
access_mms error: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:8082
main debug: no access modules matched
main error: open of `http://127.0.0.1:8082' failed
main debug: dead input
main debug: changing item without a request (current 1/2)
main debug: nothing to play
qt4 debug: IM: Deleting the input
```

Answer (score 0):

> and checked on "Display locally"

uncheck this and you get your goal

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in the name of the file for the stream - smth like videostream.asf after the IP of the camera like:

```
> http://127.0.0.1/videostream.asf
```

I do not know ig you are using GUI of CLI, but of it is GUI adding the name of the file should prompt you to enter password and user name in a new pop up window. With CLI is is a bit more trickier....

Comment: I am not playing a file it is a live stream.

Comment: it is the file for a livestream

Comment: http://www.coolutils.com/formats/asf